# Xubuntu 14.04 theme error

Tags: xubuntu, themes

so I installed Xubuntu 14.04 and I tried to change to the pre-installed theme Numix but only the part under the title bar changed for file manager. That goes with every other theme. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appearance properties are in two locations:

1. Settings Manager -> Appearance (Gtk theme, icons, fonts)
2. Settings Manager -> Window Manager (Window manager (titlebar))

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sean! Sorry for the very late response but I was away.